# Hangfire run twice in two high availability servers

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have `hangfire` recurring In two high availability servers and the problem is that every job get run twice, I want to prevent all job to be ran twice.
It’s implemented in ASP.NET CORE.

We need solution please to solve this problem

Comment: What kind of database is used? Each has its own pro and cons. Depending on the database Hangfire recommends different configuration settings and each type has different guarantees about atomicity which can also be configured. I would guess there is your root cause.

Comment: How did you register the recurring job? Do you check if it exists before registering it?

Comment: this seems to be a common Hangfire issue. see this discussion https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1025

Comment: Sample of the code:

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate($"{Environment.MachineName}-HangfireMigrateData",
               () => HangfireJobRunner.HangfireFunc(_MigrateConsumptionPointsPoint, userInput), _MigrateConsumptionPointsCron);

Comment: It's SQL SERVER database. Note: avalivality servers are both active at the same time

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.